# Vue-cli виснет при создании проекта

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, node-modules, vue-cli

Пытаюсь создать новый проект через vue-cli. Выполнение виснет после того, как доходит до стадии выбора описания проекта. Нажатие `Enter` или `Ctrl+C/Ctrl+D` ничего не даёт. Вообще ни на какие клавиши не реагирует. Пробовал переустанавливать `node.js` и `vue.cli`. Не помогло. Вот как это выглядит:
[image: Вот как это выглядит:]
Что мне с этим делать?

Comment: а описание писать пробовали?

Comment: Да. Нет эффекта.

Comment: попробуйте написать `vue create project-name`

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало, но мне пришлось обновить версию. `vue create project-name` работает. Но `vue init` не работает даже на новой версии. Всё тоже самое.

Comment: для 3-й версии другой синтаксис https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/creating-a-project.html#%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1n%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B4n%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-2-x-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Я видел руководство и устанавливал плагин `@vue/cli-init`. Но, как я уже говорил, создание всё ещё виснет на стадии выбора описания проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло полное удаление всего, свзяанного с `nodejs` и `npm` (видимо, криво установил), и последующая [установка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNjnM0Fyn4E) их при помощи `nvm`